# My cron job is always containing the same token values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, cron, node-schedule

I'm trying to create a cron job that every minute will make an API request to refresh the session. In the request I send `refreshToken` as request body. The refresh token, I get it from the store. Bellow is my request.

**api.actions.js**

```
export const getAccessToken = () => {
  const { refreshToken } = store.getState(); // getting refreshToken from store
  return apiDefaultAction({
    url: ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
    },
    onSuccess: apiData => {
      return {
        type: ACCESS_TOKEN_SUCCESS,
        payload: { ...apiData },
      };
    },
  });
};
```

The request response is a new `accessToken` and `refreshToken`.
The reducer than updates the store with a new `accessToken` and `refreshToken`:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case ACCESS_TOKEN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        accessToken: action.payload.accessToken,
        refreshToken: action.payload.refreshToken,
      };
  }
};
```

I initiate the cron job calling this method inside a component:

```
import schedule from 'node-schedule';

const RUN_EVERY_MINUTE = '0 * * * * *';

export const initiateAccessToken = () => {
  schedule.scheduleJob(RUN_EVERY_MINUTE, () => {
    store.dispatch(getAccessToken());
  });
};
```

However when the requests are happening every minute, the `refreshToken` is always the same, from the first state. First request receives 200, the rest of the requests are not passing because the `refreshToken` is not having the updated value from the store and it is expired.

I checked the states before and after the request redux is updating the `refreshToken` values after the request, but in the cron job is always having the same token. Any ideas why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

I tried bellow example and the button value isn't changing as well:|

```
import React from 'react';
import schedule from 'node-schedule';

const RUN_EVERY_10_SEC = '0,10 * * * * *';

const TestComponent = () => {
  let value = 0;
  schedule.scheduleJob(RUN_EVERY_10_SEC, () => {
    value += 1;
  });
  const Button = <button>{value}</button>;
  return <div>{Button}</div>;
};

export default TestComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason, I believe, is because your `node-schedule` code saves a reference to your arbitrary function when you first run it. **That means it'll always keep a reference to the store in its initial state and it explains why you're not seeing the update.**

Probably the best solution is to pass the store as a dependency on the function:

```js
import schedule from 'node-schedule';

const RUN_EVERY_MINUTE = '0 * * * * *';

export const initiateAccessToken = (store) => {
  schedule.scheduleJob(RUN_EVERY_MINUTE, () => {
    store.dispatch(getAccessToken());
  });
};
```

This way your function would always have a new and updated reference to your store.

Comment: yes, I tried this way in the first place, but didn't helped. It's basically the same way, same token every time, but one more problem is that, dispatch is not working (not sure, why) if I pass the entire store as a parameter

Comment: I tried the example from the **UPDATE** section, the value doesn't seem to update as well